# Can I log unhandled exceptions but keep the standard crash dialog?

Tags: winforms, exception

By default, when a Winforms app crashes you get a dialog that says "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. [...]" and this dialog allows you to quit the app or to try to ignore the exception and continue. I want to keep this behavior, but I also want to add custom logging code for unhandled exceptions.

I tried adding my logging code to the `Application.ThreadException` event, but it seems that adding any event handler here causes the standard dialog to no longer be shown.

Is there any way I can add logging code while also preserving the standard exception dialog window?